# Stuck in loading raster to PostGIS

Tags: postgis, raster, postgresql

I am running running Mac OS X (10.7.5), PostgreSQL (9.2) and PostGIS (2.0.2) (installed via [Postgres.app](http://postgresapp.com/)).

The PostGIS extension seems to work perfectly with vector and raster layers. Once I enable PostGIS for the specific database I am able to create vector and rasters from the SQL Editor of phpAdmin3 (like with ST_MakeEmptyRaster).

The problems begin when I try to load a raster with raster2pgsql. I have no great experience with Postgres (or DBMS in general) so what I did might appear stupid...

I tried to launch it via psql following this steps:

1) Open psql terminal;

2) typed `\c mydatabase`;

3) Got as prompt `mydatabase=#` (that I guess means I am logged with owner rights...;

4) Now I tried `raster2pgsql -G`but of course is no SQL so I got `ERROR:  syntax error at or near "raster2pgsql" LINE 1: raster2pgsql -G;`

Then I went back to my Mac OS X terminal shell and into the the folder where my raster2pgsql file is located (/usr/local/pgsql/bin) and typed `raster2pgsql -s 4236 -I -C -M *.tif -F -t 100x100 /my/path/to/the/file/myfile.tif myrastertable | psql -U myuser -d mydb -h localhost -p 5432` but I got `-bash: raster2pgsql: command not found`.

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: I actually solved the problem by reinstalling Postgres & PostGIS with the homebrew installation (here [link] (http://lukeberndt.com/2011/postgres-postgis-on-osx-lion)). No idea why Postegres.app didn't work for the raster...

Answer (score 3):

In Windows, the raster2pgsql file is in

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\PostgreSQL\9.1\bin>raster2pgsql
```

In Linux, it's in

```
/usr/bin (ubuntu)
```

In OSX, I have no idea, but have you tried to search it? And yes, that fifth way was the right way.

Comment: Thank you very much. My problem in Ubuntu was solved using your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Postgresapp's tools are in a different location - `/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.3/bin`. To use a given tool, prepend the full path:

```
/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.3/bin/raster2pgsql -s 4236 -I -C -M *.tif -F -t 100x100 /my/path/to/the/file/myfile.tif myrastertable | psql -U myuser -d mydb -h localhost -p 5432
```

Alternatively, add the directory to your PATH or use alias:

```
alias raster2pgsql="/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.3/bin/raster2pgsql"
```

For permanency, add that line to your `.bashrc` file.

Comment: the paths mentioned here are correct but ancient. Later versions of PostgresApp do contain a symlink called `latest` to the latest included PostgreSQL binaries. To add these to your `$PATH` the recommended way is: `sudo mkdir -p /etc/paths.d && echo /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin | sudo tee /etc/paths.d/postgresapp` make sure to open a new terminal window afterwards!

Answer (score 0):

Since Mac OS X is a UNIX based system you should check the file permissions first.

```
> ls -l raster2pgsql
```

> -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 200096 May 23 15:03 raster2pgsql

If it looks like this than you could try to write it like

```
> ./raster2pgsql
```

If this works, than your installation directory

> /usr/local/pgsql/bin

is not in the PATH
check your PATH variable

```
> $PATH
```

If it is not there check out how to put it in your PATH.
The syntax depend very much on the shell you use.
It looks like 'bash' in your case, so use

```
> export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/pgsql/bin
```

That should solve the problem about not finding the executable.
This would be the exact description of your problem.

To make the export permanent, add that to your `~/.bashrc` file. Takes effect after re-logging in, or after sourcing the file with something like `source ~/.bashrc`.
Or, to make the export permanent after reboot, for the entire system, add that to the `/etc/profile.d/pgsql.sh` file (this may verify by system). The file name itself if arbitrary for a setup like that, and does not need to be executable.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable the command-line tools to work from your shell

```
sudo ln -sf /usr/share/postgresql-common/pg_wrapper /usr/local/bin/shp2pgsql

sudo ln -sf /usr/share/postgresql-common/pg_wrapper /usr/local/bin/pgsql2shp

sudo ln -sf /usr/share/postgresql-common/pg_wrapper /usr/local/bin/raster2pgsql
```